# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: colo

Tags: java, android

Hy guys,

I have an error concerning the SQL query. I can not find the mistake, I think it comes from the moment I create my table. If you could help me it would be great.

```
public class dbVariablesCreate {
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.todolist.vladmac.mytodolist.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE = "table_task";
    public static final String COL_TASK = "task";
    public static final String COL_COLOR = "colo";
}
```

}

```
    public class dbRequery extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public dbRequery(Context context) {
    super(context, dbVariablesCreate.DB_NAME, null, dbVariablesCreate.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  /*  String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
            dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_TASK+" TEXT, "+dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_COLOR+ " TEXT);";*/

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_TASK + " TEXT, " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_COLOR + " TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Requery

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry._ID + ", " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_TASK ", " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.COL_COLOR + " FROM " + dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE, null);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this requery

```
public Cursor queryAll(){
        //get a READABLE database instance:
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbRequery.getReadableDatabase();

        //query all:
        //db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE,null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
             null );
        return cursor ;
    }
```

Comment: When I use "com.todolist.vladmac.mytodolist" I have an error : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM com.todolist.vladmac.mytodolist. 

But if I replace "com.todolist.vladmac.mytodolist" by  dbVariablesCreate.TaskEntry.TABLE error disappear and the program run.